# Add NSView from different nib

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller

How can I add a subview when the new view is in a different xib file?

The class for the different nib is an NSViewController and I'm using `self = [super initWithNibName:@"NewView" bundle:nil];` to load the nib

Can I just do something like:

```
NewView *nv = [NewView new];
[oldView removeFromSuperView];
[mv addSubview:[nv theView]];
```

or do I have to do something different

Comment: When you say "the class for the different nib is an NSViewController", do you mean the File's Owner?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct, providing `NewView` is a subclass of `NSViewController`. Having said that, you shouldn't name a controller class `NewView`, as it's not a view. Your subclass of `NSViewController` should really be named `NewViewController`.

You can also do this:

```
[[oldView superview] replaceSubview:oldView withView:nv];
```

Of course, this assumes that your `NewView` nib file has its File's Owner set your subclass of `NSViewController`.